# How do i use a variable in the columns section of an ajax request for data tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to add dynamic values for the column section in an ajax request so that the users can have control over what fields are in the data tables.

I tried with default values and it worked but when i changed to use dynamic values from a variable, the ajax field gives me errors

this works fine;

```
$(function() {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{{ route('members.create') }}',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                    { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                    { data: 'address', name: 'address' },
                    { data: 'contact', name: 'contact' },
                    { data: 'nationality', name: 'nationality' },
                    { data: 'dob', name: 'dob' },
                    { data: 'hometown', name: 'hometown' },
                    { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false }
                ]
            });
        });
```

this is where the problem comes in;

```
$(function() {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{{ route('members.create') }}',
                columns: [
                    var memberFields = <?php echo json_encode($chosen_member_fields, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>;
                    for(var i = 0; i < memberFields.length; i++){
                        { data: memberFields[i], name: memberFields[i] };
                    },
                    { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false }
                ]
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `column` property wants an `array` .
And your structure to build array is incorrect .
Do this :

```
$(function() {

    var memberFields = <?php echo json_encode($chosen_member_fields, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>;
    var columnArray = [];//To save for value into an Array
    for(var i = 0; i < memberFields.length; i++){
        columnArray.push({ data: memberFields[i], name: memberFields[i] });//push valuse to array
    },
    columnArray.push({ data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false });//push last value

    $('#myTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{{ route('members.create') }}',
                columns: columnArray ,  //just say Array name !
    });

});
```

Didnt test but hope works